# How to change clock frequency of STM32L432KC

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

I am not entirely sure whats going on here. I think I'm changing the right registers but when it comes to trying to enable the ADC clock and GPIOA clock and etc there's no write action, I can't write anything into the register. Any Ideas?

When I say can't write anything into the register I mean the RCC->AHB2ENR

[Reference Sheet: STM32L432KC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx42xxx43xxx44xxx45xxx46xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Code:

```
void initClock(){

    RCC->CR |= (1<<3); // Enable: MSIRANGE in CR
    RCC->CR &= ~(1<<7); //
    RCC->CR |= (1<<6); //
    RCC->CR |= (1<<5); // 
    RCC->CR &= ~(1<<4); // MSI Clock = 4MHz

    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(1<<12); //
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= ((1<<13) | (1<<11)); // PLLN = 40
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1<<0); // PLLSRC = MSI

    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= (1<<25); //PLLSAI1R = 4
    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~(1<<12);
    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= ((1<<8) | (1<<9) | (1<<11) | (1<<13)); //PLLSAI1N = 43

    RCC->CR |= (1<<24); // Enable: PLL
    while(((RCC->CR) & (1<<25)) == 0); //Wait till PLL is ready

    RCC->CR |= (1<<26); // Enable: PLLSAI1
    while(((RCC->CR) & (1<<27)) == 0); // Wait till PLLSAI1 is ready

    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1<<24); // Enable: PLLREN Goes into System Clock 
    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= (1<<24);  //Enable: PLLSAI1REN Goes into ADC

    RCC->CFGR |= ((1<<1) | (1<<0)); // use the PLL as system clock
}
```

Comment: What PLL settings you are tryingn to set? What will be the resulting PLL input, VCO out, and resulting system and peripheral clocks? Are they within allowed min/max limits? Why still keep toggling bits manually, instead of using bit names? Why not use ST libraries to stop reinventing the wheel (drivers) and focus on the car (the application)? Did you even read how ST libraries do it?

Comment: Trying to achieve clock frequency of 80Mhz and an ADC clock of 43MHz. In the PLL n = 40 and everything Else is default pllm = 1 and pllr = 2. In the pllsai pllsain = 43 , pllsair = 4. I found the configure combination through that HAL GUI it didn’t return an error so I am assuming it’d a valid clock setup

Comment: Unrelated to the question, some misc advise: Drop the "magic numbers", you are forcing the reader of your code to have their nose glued to the manual in order to make sense of this code. For example, instead of `(1<<24); // Enable: PLLREN ` you should have PLLCFGR |= PLLREN;`.

Comment: And even more importantly, never write to hardware registers in several steps like this! You should instead do something like `uint32_t rcc_cr = THIS | THAT... ;` ... `RCC->CR = rcc_cr;`. This generates a single write in the machine code, instead of the numerous writes you have currently. And writing to hardware regs often come with nasty side effects like "write once" or "clear by writing 1" etc, so writing to them in several steps as a habit is to line up for subtle bug creation.

Comment: Also note that `1<<31` specifically invokes undefined behavior in C and is always a bug because it shifts data into the sign bit of the signed `int` made up by the integer constant `1`, so your coding style is dangerous. Make a habit of always using unsigned integer constants: `1u<<31`.

Comment: Thank you for the kind advise. Will use them moving forward cheers

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. Had to change the Flash wait state.

```
void initClock(){

    FLASH->ACR |= 1<<2;

    RCC->CR |= 1<<3;

    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(1<<12); //
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= ((1<<13) | (1<<11)); // PLLN = 40
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1<<0); // PLLSRC = MSI

    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= (1<<25); //PLLSAI1R = 4
    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~(1<<12);
    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= ((1<<8) | (1<<9) | (1<<11) | (1<<13)); //PLLSAI1N = 43

    RCC->CR |= (1<<24); // Enable: PLL
    while(((RCC->CR) & (1<<25)) == 0); //Wait till PLL is ready

    RCC->CR |= (1<<26); // Enable: PLLSAI1
    while(((RCC->CR) & (1<<27)) == 0); // Wait till PLLSAI1 is ready

    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1<<24); // Enable: PLLREN Goes into System Clock 
    RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= (1<<24);  //Enable: PLLSAI1REN Goes into ADC

    RCC->CFGR |= ((1<<1) | (1<<0));
}
```